# dlopen fails with "library not found error" android ndk

Tags: android, linux, g++, native

I am trying to dynamically load a library which is present in vendor/lib64 folder in my Samsung s20 device.
when i copied library to system/lib64 library is getting loaded is their any better workaround for this issue.

Answer (score -1):

We can Open Lib using VNDK. since opening vendor so is not allowed.